# How to modify absolute Page URL of the virtual pageview in Google Tag Manager to perform Cross Domain tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

The user flows through two domains in order to complete the end goal. Eg workflow:

The user lands on www.abc.com and then goes to video.xyz.com to complete the end goal. In order to see the whole journey of the user, we had set up cross-domain tracking but the challenge we are facing is video.xyz.com does not allow query parameters and hence the linker parameter (_ga) does not get appended to the URL.

Hence in GA, we see 2 users for an individual user.

The workaround we tried was to create a virtual pageview on link click (link present on www.abc.com) which directs the user to video.xyz.com and tried modifying the location (Document Location URL) parameter with customTask without much luck. Listing down the steps that we followed,

1. Got linker parameter from www.abc.com
2. Set location parameter to URL - video.xyz.com?{{linkerparameter}}
3. Sent a virtual pageview with the above URL

I hope I was able to clear my situation here. I have been stuck with this for more than 2 days now.

Any help would be really helpful.

Code to retrieve Linker Param:

```
function() {
  var dataLayer = window.dataLayer;
  return function(model) {
    var galinkerParam = model.get('linkerParam');
    dataLayer.push({'event':'linkerParamReady',
                    'galinkerParam':galinkerParam});
      }

}
```

Code to form URL:

```
function() {
    return 'video.xyz.com' + '?'+ {{GA Linker Variable}};
}
```

Code to modify Document Location URL:

```
function() {
  var dataLayer = window.dataLayer;
  return function(model) {
    var cid = model.get('clientId');
    dataLayer.push({'event':'trackerReady',
                    'cid':cid});
    var locationurl = model.get('location');
    dataLayer.push({'event':'locationReady',
                    'locationurl':locationurl});
    model.set('location', {{GA Virtual Pageview URL}} );
  }

}
```

Comment: I do not quite understand how you think this will enable cross domain tracking for you. If you want to record the click on abc.com as belonging to video.com then you do not need the linker (since the client id will be retrieved from abc.com regardless of what you write to the location field), and the setup will still not transmit the client id to the other domain. If video.com does not take query parameters you could test if hashes are allowed and use the url hash to send the parameter (GTM has a setting for that).

Comment: Hi Eike

Thank you for your response. Passing the linker param was a workaround I was testing but didn't get success. The major challenge I'm facing here is query parameters not getting attached to the video.xyz.com URL. That's why looking for a workaround to setup cross-domain tracking.